# Specification of libraries in a an Applet tag for an application hosted in Tomcat

Tags: html, tomcat, applet

I have an application with an embedded applet.   When the applet is downloaded into the user's browser it also brings down a some jars that are used by the applet.   Right now these other jars are located in the same directory as the applet.   The applet tag in the html looks like this:

```
 ARCHIVE ="CoderDx.jar,xpp3-1.1.3.4.C.jar,xml-apis.jar,jcommon-1.0.16.jar,jfreechart-
1.0.13.jar,MultiSplit.jar,balloontip-1.1.1.jar,artificialmed.jar" WIDTH=99% HEIGHT=100%>
```

CoderDx.jar is the applet.   The others are just additional jars.

But suppose I wanted to put these additional jars in the \WEB-INF\lib directory.    I'm not sure how to indicate this within the tag so that it works within Tomcat.   I've tried some obvious possibilities but so far no luck.

Thank you,

Elliott

Answer (score 1):

For the applet to find the libraries, they must be reachable by HTTP. Putting them in the library directory of you web application does not help.